# Wordpress get_pages() returns incorrect number of posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to traverse a list of pages, using get_pages(), however for some reason, if I set the sort_column or sort_order it varies the amount of posts and I can't understand why.

Here is a simple example:

```
$pages = get_pages( array(
  'number' => 3,
  'sort_order'  =>  'DESC',
  'sort_column' => 'post_modified'
));
var_dump($pages);
```

This returns an array of size 2 (2 pages)

If I remove the sort_order, then it returns 1 and if I remove both sort_order AND sort_column, then it returns the expected 3 pages

Can anyone see anything stupid I am doing or explain why "sort_column" or sort_order should return a different array size.

If I was using post_type etc, I could understand, however this has me baffled.

I checked that all three posts had a post_modified and I tried post_date, but it returned the exact same data.

Comment: I'm stumped on this, I did a test on one of my sites and the results are random, can't create the same issues as you even. If I use the default settings and set number => 3 I'm only getting 1 post returned. I never actaully use get_pages() not sure if I had trouble in the past or not bt I tend to use get_posts() or a WP_Query. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: @Paul don't be sorry, I am pleased that you went to the trouble of trying it and confirming I wasn't going crazy !